# Enabling and disabling app notifications using code

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am in the process of creating a digital detox app which allows the user to snooze all notifications, calls, messages etc for a given period of time in order to stop the user from being distracted by his phone and focus better on his work. I am making this app using unity and C#.

After researching on the topic for a while, I still wasn't able to find a clear way to disable app notifications. Is there a clear way to do this using code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.